# Subshells in Bash, using crontab

Tags: linux, bash, cron, cron-task

I am currently working on some school project where we should be dealing with cron jobs, basically, we are building a simple CLI to do CRUD operations using Bash.

I found this snippet of code that inserts a new job into my crontab, yet I have no idea how it works... I understand it uses subshell and pipes, yet I just don't know why I would have to do it

```
    read job
    { crontab -l; echo "$job"; } | crontab -
```

Answer (score 1):

`crontab` is a file which contains jobs (instructions) for `cron` daemon (time-based job scheduler for Unix operating system).

If you put your bash lines into a script , let's say `cron_test.sh`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/sh

read job
    { crontab -l; echo "$job"; } | crontab -
```

And afterwards if you execute the script `./cron_test.sh`, you'll see that the scripts awaits from stdin your input (which stores it into variable named job) in order to create a new job for your user.

Be careful because you have to respect the job syntax:

`1 2 3 4 5 /path/to/command arg1 arg2`

where:

```
1: Minute (0-59)
2: Hours (0-23)
3: Day (0-31)
4: Month (0-12 [12 == December])
5: Day of the week(0-7 [7 or 0 == sunday])
/path/to/command – Script or command name to schedule
```

Some commands:

`crontab -l` -  list current crontab (for the user which you're using)

`crontab -e` - edit the crontab file